# SU(2) and entangled particles

Tags: linear-algebra, mp.mathematical-physics, oa.operator-algebras, quantum-mechanics

We have two particles $A$ and $B$ in a maximally entangled state $|\Psi\rangle \in \cal{H}_A \times \cal{H}_B$
$$
\left|\Psi\right\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} ( \left| 0 
\right\rangle_A\otimes \left| 0 \right\rangle_B +  \left| 1 
\right\rangle_A\otimes \left| 1 \right\rangle_B ),
$$
where $_A\left\langle i | j \right\rangle_A = {_B\left\langle i | j \right\rangle_B} =
\delta_{ij}$ and $U^T$ is the transpose of the matrix $U$.

It is claimed that if $U \in SU(\cal{H}_A)$, then
$$
U \otimes I \left|\Psi\right\rangle = I \otimes U^T \left|\Psi\right\rangle
$$

How can we show this to be true? I am trying to make sense of a "quantum game theory" paper, but it assumes a high comfort level with the mathematical apparatus of quantum physics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is presumably simply an issue of notation -
\begin{eqnarray}
U\otimes I
\left|\Psi\right\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left( (U_{11} \left| 0 \right\rangle_A + U_{21} \left| 1 \right\rangle_A ) \otimes \left| 0 \right\rangle_B \\
\hspace{3cm} + ( U_{12} \left| 0 \right\rangle_A + U_{22} \left| 1 
\right\rangle_A ) \otimes \left| 1 \right\rangle_B \right)
\end{eqnarray}
and
\begin{eqnarray}
I\otimes U^T \left|\Psi\right\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left( \left| 0 \right\rangle_A \otimes (U_{11} \left| 0 \right\rangle_B + U_{12} \left| 1 \right\rangle_B ) \\
\hspace{3cm} + \ \left| 1 \right\rangle_A \otimes ( U_{21} \left| 0 \right\rangle_B + U_{22} \left| 1 \right\rangle_B ) \right)
\end{eqnarray}
They're indeed the same.

Comment: Thanks for this. The bra-ket notation really does make things clear, once you get used to it!